# How to apply fit line for different lines that have different trends including linear and cubic in one scatter plot graph in SPSS?

Tags: spss, curve-fitting

I have got a scatter plot with three treatments and would like to apply the
best fit line for each treatments.  Is there any way in SPSS to apply fit lines in one treatment without affecting others at one figure. 
Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: I just answered a very similar question over at the [NABBLE SPSS group](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/different-fit-lines-for-different-groups-td5714524.html#a5714525) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is verbatim what I posted on the [NABBLE SPSS list-serve](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/different-fit-lines-for-different-groups-td5714524.html#a5714525) to a synonymous question:

> Here is the best solution I could come up with. In a nutshell it makes
>   two grouping variables and then maps the one group to a 100%
>   transparent element. Then it just has two element calls in the GPL (in
>   this example one for linear and one for quadratic).
>
> Of course the most flexible solution would be to actually fit the
>   models for each group and put the predicted values as a new variable
>   in the dataset, but this didn't work out too badly (the legend didn't
>   even turn out that badly).

```
**********************************************.
set seed = 10.
input program.
loop #i = 1 to 100.
if #i <= 50 group = 0.
if #i > 50 group = 1.
end case.
end loop.
end file.
end input program.
dataset name sim.
execute.

compute x = RV.NORM(0,1).
if group = 0 outcome =  x + RV.NORM(0,0.1).
if group = 1 outcome =  x**2 + RV.NORM(0,0.1).

compute group_square = (group = 1).
compute group_linear = (group = 0).
formats all (F1.0).
exe.


DATASET ACTIVATE sim.
* Chart Builder.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=x outcome group_square group_linear group
    MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: x=col(source(s), name("x"))
  DATA: outcome=col(source(s), name("outcome"))
  DATA: group=col(source(s), name("group"), unit.category())
  DATA: group_square=col(source(s), name("group_square"), unit.category())
  DATA: group_linear=col(source(s), name("group_linear"), unit.category())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("x"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("outcome"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.transparency), null())     
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.transparency), map(("0", transparency."1.0"), ("1", transparency."0.0")))
  ELEMENT: point(position(x*outcome), color.exterior(group))
  ELEMENT: line(position(smooth.linear(x*outcome)), transparency.interior(group_linear), color.interior(group))
  ELEMENT: line(position(smooth.quadratic(x*outcome)), transparency.interior(group_square), color.interior(group))
END GPL.
**********************************************.
```

[image: curves with different fit lines]
<sub>(source: [nabble.com](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/file/n5714525/mapping_aethetics1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

First, when you create the scatter plot make sure you say "x with y by z" where z is the variable defining groups that will  each get their own fit line.  There is a button in the graphing editor window for applying multiple fit lines.  It's right next to the single-fit-line button.  You can also use the menus.  i don't know of a way to create these lines with syntax except in older versions that had the "interactive graph" capability.

Once you have your fitlines, you can click, wait a second, and click again to select just one, and then you can use the properties dialog box to change it to a quadratic, cubic, or loess line.

Comment: This will make the fit lines for each group be the same, which it seems the OP wants different fit lines for each group. See the comment to the question for an example of adding in fit lines via syntax in inline GPL statements (FYI you can do the fit lines you suggest though through the Chart Builder dialog in the GUI though).

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but I would upvote your answer if you capitalized your I's.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I modified my Syntax for three lines as follows but it was unsuccessful, could you please have a look at my commend and let me know where I have gone wrong. Thanks a lot

Comment: /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Week stHWEOC Treatment Treatment_cubic Treatment_linear Treatment_linear
 MISSING=LISTWISE 
REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.

Comment: BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Week=col(source(s), name("Week"))
  DATA: stHWEOC=col(source(s), name("stHWEOC"))
  DATA: Treatment=col(source(s), name("Treatment"), unit.category())
  DATA: Treatment_cubic=col(source(s), name("Treatment_cubic"), unit.category())
  DATA: Treatment_linear=col(source(s), name("Treatment_linear"), unit.category())
  DATA: Treatment_linear=col(source(s), name("Treatment_linear"), unit.category())

Comment: GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Week"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("stHWEOC"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.transparency), null())     
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.transparency), map(("0", transparency."1.0"), ("1", transparency."0.0")))

Comment: ELEMENT: point(position(Week*stHWEOC), color.exterior(Treatment))
  ELEMENT: line(position(smooth.linear(Week*stHWEOC)), transparency.interior(Treatment_linear), color.interior(Treatment))
  ELEMENT: line(position(smooth.linear(Week*stHWEOC)), transparency.interior(Treatment_linear), color.interior(Treatment))
  ELEMENT: line(position(smooth.cubic(Week*stHWEOC)), transparency.interior(Treatment_cubic), color.interior(Treatment))
END GPL.

Comment: @Shahla, please update your original question with the complete code statement, including fake data that functionally replicates your data. The only thing I can tell in your statements is that you have a redundant set of variables and element statements for `Treatment_linear`.

Comment: @AndyW, Thanks Andy, my data set is a repeated measurement with three treatments so it includes 1st column Week (repeated measurement), 2nd column is Treatment (3 treatments)and 3rd column contains my variable (stHWEOC in above example). Two of treatments are linear and one of them is cubic and I would like to apply fit line for each treatment separately. I would like to place a fake data as you requested but I do not know how it can be pasted here, I looked at the help but it was not really helpful.

Comment: I am placing my fake data set here, but not sure if it reads easily. -8 1 1.3,
-8 1 1.6,
-8 1 1.6,
-8 2 -2.7,
-8 2 -2.1,
-8 2 4.1,
-8 3 -1.0,
-8 3 -1.4,
-8 3 2.4,
1 1 -2.7,
1 1 -0.9,
1 1 -1.7,
1 2 -15.1,
1 2 -10.0,
1 2 -10.3,
1 3 -4.3,
1 3 -0.9,
1 3 5.3,
10 1 -1.3,
10 1 2.1,
10 1 3.8,
10 2 -9.4,
10 2 -12.2,
10 2 -9.9,
10 3 -0.7,
10 3 -2.5,
10 3 3.2,

Comment: @Shahla, Please see this [blog post of mine](http://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/making-a-reproducible-example-in-spss/) about making a reproducible example in SPSS. Edit your original question with this information.